# How to make my function work for only for one section

Tags: javascript

[image]

Hello I am select boxes when I click on select all, Right now it's selection all the boxes on the page, But I have to make it section specific, Means when I click on "select all" of A section. It should select all A section's boxes, not of section B or C. How to make my selection section specific. plz check image for better understanding

## css

```
        .box {
            background:red;
            padding:10px;
            width:200px;
            display:none;
        }

        .toggle-check-group {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
}

.slider {
    cursor: url('../img/pest_cursor.svg'), move !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    transition: .1s;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .8rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: top .1s;
}

    .slider:hover {
        top: -5px;
    }


input:checked + .slider {
    color: #188a80;
    background-color: #daf1ef;
    border: 1px solid #188a80;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.slider::selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-moz-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-webkit-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
```

## html

```
 <div class="card" style="background:#ff000014; padding:10px;">
        <div class="card-header " id="Div1">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
                                                                    <img src="select_all.png" class="check-all " onclick="Toggle()" />
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>


        <div id="Div2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div id="Div3" class="category-list list-style-none">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <br />
        <br />
    <div class="card" style="background:#f8f6ef; padding:10px;">
        <div class="card-header " id="Div4">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
                                                                    <img src="select_all.png" class="check-all " onclick="Toggle()" />
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>


        <div id="Div5" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div id="Div6" class="category-list list-style-none">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    <div class="card" style="background:#ebebf1; padding:10px;">
        <div class="card-header " id="Div7">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
                                                                    <img src="select_all.png" class="check-all " onclick="Toggle()" />
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>


        <div id="Div8" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div id="Div9" class="category-list list-style-none">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <div class="toggle-check-group">

                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                                <label class="switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pestname" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## JS

```
 <script>
      //get all elements with tag name input
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");

      

      //create toggle function
      function Toggle() {
          //iterate over all checkboxes and mark check = true
          for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
              if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox')
                  checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
          }
      }


    </script>
```

Comment: In your JS you select all the inputs so that's normal to happen. You can give your 2 ul's a different id and when you click the button pass in Toggle function that id and then select the inputs that are descedants of that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Not a perfect solution

```
function Toggle(e) {
  const getClassClicked = e.target.getAttribute("data-class");
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
    `.${getClassClicked} ul li input`
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].type === "checkbox")
      checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
  }
}
```

[Code Sand Box For Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-water-zspk2u?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

(advice: you need to learn more about JS)

```js
//get all elements with tag name input
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myinput");
      //create toggle function
      function Toggle_1() {
          //iterate over all checkboxes and mark check = true
          for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
              if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkboxes[i].name === 'sectionA')
                  checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
          }
      }
      function Toggle_2() {
          //iterate over all checkboxes and mark check = true
          for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
              if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkboxes[i].name === 'sectionB')
                  checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
          }
      }
      function Toggle_3() {
          //iterate over all checkboxes and mark check = true
          for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
              if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkboxes[i].name === 'sectionC')
                  checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
          }
      }
```

```css
 .box {
            background:red;
            padding:10px;
            width:200px;
            display:none;
        }

        .toggle-check-group {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
}

.slider {
  
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    transition: .1s;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .8rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: top .1s;
}

    .slider:hover {
        top: -5px;
    }


input:checked + .slider {
    color: #188a80;
    background-color: #daf1ef;
    border: 1px solid #188a80;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.slider::selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-moz-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */
.slider::-webkit-selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="card" style="background:#ff000014; padding:10px;">
         <div class="card-header " id="Div1">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
               <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
               <button class="check-all " onclick="Toggle_1()" />
               </a>
            </h5>
         </div>
         <div id="Div2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div id="Div3" class="category-list list-style-none">
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionA" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="card" style="background:#f8f6ef; padding:10px;">
         <div class="card-header " id="Div4">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
               <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
               <button class="check-all " onclick="Toggle_2()" />
               </a>
            </h5>
         </div>
         <div id="Div5" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div id="Div6" class="category-list list-style-none">
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionB" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="card" style="background:#ebebf1; padding:10px;">
         <div class="card-header " id="Div7">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <h5 class="mb-0 ">
               <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cp2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsecroptwo">Select All
               <button class="check-all " onclick="Toggle_3()" />
               </a>
            </h5>
         </div>
         <div id="Div8" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingcroptwo" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div id="Div9" class="category-list list-style-none">
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="toggle-check-group">
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll()"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-1</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-2</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll();"><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-3</span></label>
                           <label class="switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="sectionC" title="3" class="myinput" onclick="CheckUnCheckAll(); "><span class="slider" name="pname" title="PNAME">Option-4</span></label>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="src/script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you select all the inputs so that's normal to happen. Since you already have id's for the different Divs you can pass in Toggle function the id of the div you clicked and then select the inputs that are descedants of that id

```
<script>

  function Toggle(id) {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} .myinput`);
      for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox')
              checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
      }
  }


</script>
```

Apart from this you will need to add event listeners to the buttons which will call `Toggle(e.target.id)`